# How to check the actual votes of a given answer/question?

Tags: support, reputation, vote-count

Suppose that I give an answer to a question and I get 2 upvotes and 2 downvotes. 
The reputation of that answer is supposed to be 16 ( 10x2 - 2x2 ).
If you look at the question you will just see 0 as the numbers of upvotes/downvotes, giving the impression that the question has never received an upvote or an downvote.
Is there a way to know the number of downvotes and upvotes to deduct the reputation of the answer?

Comment: You need to click the vote number and it will show you the upvotes/downvotes for the post.

Comment: The net reputation gained from that post is already reflected in your total reputation and you can click on the vote number which shows you the up/down votes separately. What else is that you're looking to achieve using this *feature-request*?

Comment: thank you @crypticツ . I just did not know how to check.

Comment: And I don't understand the downvotes! I was just asking about a feature I did not know about.

Comment: @R.J the feature-request tag was wrong. I have edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We already have this feature. That is a privilege to see the vote count of the post named [established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user). You need 1000 reputation to gain that privilege. You already have that privilege in Stack Overflow.

You can see the actual votes by clicking on the score. See the [privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) to see how does it work.

Comment: Thank you! Well my problem was how to check it. Will accept this as answer when the countdown is over.